# .removeEventListener(); by name or reference?

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

Say you have simple:

```
document.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

Does `removeEventListener` remove a registered listener for `click` events named `clickHandler` or does it remove a registered listener for `click` events referencing the very same function that `clickHandler` references?

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) they say:

> The event listener to be removed is identified using a combination of the event type, the event listener function itself, and various optional options that may affect the matching process

When they say "*the event listener function itself*", do they mean the very same reference?

I'm asking because I have (in a React project) a [memoized](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) function that removes a bunch of event listeners and I would like to know how often I need to get a new function.

If `removeEventListener` removes handlers by names, I can leave the dependecy array of `useCallback` empty.
But if `removeEventListener` removes by references, I need to put all the listeners in the dependency array. And maybe I would be better off without memoization.

Comment: the function passed to `removeEventListener` must reference the same function used when adding

Comment: "*When they say "the event listener function itself", do they mean the very same reference?*"... Yes

Comment: You might want to look at the `abort` option in `addEventListener`

Comment: @Jamiec and spender thank you for the answer, that was quick! I''l leave the question here in case someone else has the same doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass a reference to the same function used for `addEventListener` when calling `removeEventListener`

Answer (score 3):

In your example `clickHandler` is an [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier). Identifiers can't be converted to strings, so there is no way for JavaScript to remember if the same identifier name has been used as an argument before. They are merely names meant to be read by developers.

So yes, you will need to pass the reference to the function. Even if you pass that reference via another identifier.

```js
function clickHandler() {
  console.log('Clicked!');
}

const buttonElement = document.querySelector('button');

buttonElement.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);

setTimeout(() => {
  const differentHandlerName = clickHandler;
  buttonElement.removeEventListener('click', differentHandlerName);
  console.log('Removed event listener via a different identifier name');
}, 2000);
```

```html
<button>
  Click
</button>
```